# SOAP web services in erlang

Tags: .net, web-services, json, soap, erlang

Is there any good erlang library for creating / accessing SOAP web services?

Maybe also handling plain XML is quite difficult.

Is Json a good alternative? Any lib for that?

My goal is interop with existing .Net web services.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yaws (an Erlang Web Server) has a [Soap module](http://yaws.hyber.org/soap_intro.yaws) but Soap is not much used in the Erlang Community. Json is a better bet.

The [Mochiweb kit](http://code.google.com/p/mochiweb/) that you can used to build your own servers (don't panic its easier than it seems) has [good Json support](http://code.google.com/p/mochiweb/source/browse/trunk/src/mochijson2.erl).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to add to the above answer except that Mochiweb now has a new address: http://github.com/mochi/mochiweb